# Image on windows phone app is not updating when URI remains same but image data is change

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-ce

I am building a windows phone sample app in in C# in which I have to display an image from SD card on the UI.

For this, I have made a small function as :

```
Private void UpdateImage()
{
    BitmapImage bitmapd = new BitmapImage(new Uri(D:\\Pictures\\img1.bmp));
    FingerImage.Source = bitmapd;
}
```

This image `D:\\Pictures\\img1.bmp` file is being replaced by my application with another image dynamically. So the URI remains same and only image data is being changed.

**I need to update this new image** on the UI, for this, I am calling above function. But the above function does not update the image on UI every time, **except for the first time**. After that, the image remains same on the UI.

Comment: Do I need to use INotifyPropertyChanged handler ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution for my problem. I needed to ignore existing image cache. Below is the working code:

```
    Private void UpdateImage()
    {
        BitmapImage bitmapd = new BitmapImage(new Uri(D:\\Pictures\\img1.bmp));
        bitmapd.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.IgnoreImageCache;
        FingerImage.Source = bitmapd;
    }
```